# Authenticate user with passport through LinkedIn login

Tags: node.js, express, authentication, linkedin-api, passport.js

I have built a login system in Passport and works quite well. Now, I want to integrate LinkedIn login in my system. I already have `clientID`, `clientSecret` etc. needed to login. This is the code that is called when the LinkedIn login button is pressed.

```
passport.use('linkedin', new OAuth2Strategy({
    authorizationURL: 'https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/authorization',
    tokenURL: 'https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/accessToken',
    clientID: clientid,
    clientSecret: clientsecret,
    callbackURL: '/linkedinLogin/linkedinCallbackUrlLogin',
    passReqToCallback: true
},
function(req,accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
    console.log('authenticated');
    console.log(accessToken);
    req.session.code = accessToken;
    process.nextTick(function () {
        done(null, {
            code : req.code
        });
    });
}));
```

Both the `console.log()` calls in the callback function are successfully fired, this means I am successfully logged in through LinkedIn and I receive my access token. The part where I connect with LinkedIn is thus correct, what I am missing is the part where I actually log in the user. As you can see, the `callbackURL` points to `/linkedinLogin/linkedinCallbackUrlLogin`. This is what I do in that route:

```
app.get('/linkedinLogin/linkedinCallbackUrlLogin', passport.authenticate('linkedin', {
    session: false,
    successRedirect:'/linkedinLogin/success',
    failureRedirect:'/linkedinLogin/fail'
}));
```

I just specify a `successRedirect` and a `failureRedirect`. Note that if I put `session : true` I receive as an error `Failed to serialize user into session`, so for now I keep it to false.

The `successRedirect` is successfully called. In that route I call a `GET` request to LinkedIn to access some data about the user. I want to store this data in my DB and remember the user that logged in. This is how I do it:

```
https.get(
    {
    host: 'api.linkedin.com' ,
    path: '/v1/people/~?format=json' ,
    port:443 ,
    headers : {'Authorization': ' Bearer ' + req.session.code}
    },
    function(myres) {
        myres.on("data", function(chunk) {
            var linkedinJsonResult = JSON.parse(chunk);
            User.findOne({linkedinLogin : linkedinJsonResult.id}, function(err, userSearchResult){
                if(err) {
                    throw err;
                }

                //user found, login
                if(userSearchResult){
                    console.log(userSearchResult);
                }
                else {
                    //create user
                    var newUser = new User(
                        {
                            url : linkedinJsonResult.siteStandardProfileRequest.url,
                            name : linkedinJsonResult.firstName + " " + linkedinJsonResult.lastName,
                            linkedinLogin : linkedinJsonResult.id,
                            regDate : new Date()
                        }
                    );

                    //save user
                    newUser.save(function(err, user){
                        if(err){
                            throw err;
                        }

                        //login
                        console.log(user);
                    });
                }

            });
    });
    }
);
```

Let me explain the code there. After getting the data of the user I check the field "id" that is received. If this id matches one of my users' `linkedinLogin` field stored into the DB, I consider it already registered (the user has been found in the DB), thus I have to log him/her in. Otherwise I just create a new user using the data received from the `GET` request.

My question is, in both the cases - the user is found in my DB, or the user has to be created - how can I set `req.user` to be my user whenever it interacts with my website? Is it sufficient to just do `req.user = userSearchResult` (if the user is found, inside the `if` statement) or `req.user = user` (if the user has been created, inside the `newUser.save()` callback), or should I call some passport functions that will set it for me?

All the other passport functions related to the registration and login of users without using LinkedIn login are working fine. I am just worried about making this LinkedIn login work with passport.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

passport.js will automatically set the `req.user` object to the object you will pass as the second argument to the `done` function of the strategy callback.

This means that you should do something like this:

```
function(req,accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
    console.log('authenticated');
    console.log(accessToken);
    req.session.code = accessToken;
    process.nextTick(function () {
        // retrieve your user here
        getOrCreateUser(profile, function(err, user){
            if(err) return done(err);
            done(null, user);
        })

    });
}));
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

this code is helpul thnks but i have an issue pls if any have annswer pls clear that below api response

LinkedIn API Response:

```json
{
  "serviceErrorCode": 100,
  "message": "Not enough permissions to access: GET /me",
  "status": 403
}
```

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35512716)